# NullPointerException at DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.closeZipFile while creating Spring MVC Maven project

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting the error while creating the new maven project on clicking on 
    finish it's give error as

[image: "creating spring-mvc-archetype has encountered a problem"Failed to create project.]
While click on details it's show java.lang.NullPointerException. Please help

```
Failed to create project.
java.lang.NullPointerException``
```

Stack Trace Added:-

```
   !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2017-06-07 00:10:49.552
   !MESSAGE Error downloading archetype co.ntier:spring-mvc-archetype:1.0.2
   !STACK 0
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:420)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1002)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.loadArchetypeDescriptor(MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.java:400)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.setVisible(MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1229)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1208)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1197)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1194)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:885)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:425)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.closeZipFile(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:209)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager$1.call(ArchetypeManager.java:186)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager$1.call(ArchetypeManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager.getRequiredProperties(ArchetypeManager.java:183)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage$RequiredPropertiesLoader.run(MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
    Root exception:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.closeZipFile(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:209)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager$1.call(ArchetypeManager.java:186)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager$1.call(ArchetypeManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager.getRequiredProperties(ArchetypeManager.java:183)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage$RequiredPropertiesLoader.run(MavenProjectWizardArchetypeParametersPage.java:457)
at
```

org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)

Comment: I guess you forgot to attach screenshot.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: @avojak It's not showing any other error can you please guide me where I can found the full stack trace

Comment: @AsifSheikh Check in <workspace_directory>/.metadata/.log

Comment: @avojak  Stack trace added please check now and help.

Comment: Looks like it have problems download the archertype '   !MESSAGE Error downloading archetype co.ntier:spring-mvc-archetype:1.0.2. Check the network setting in Eclipse.

Comment: @MinhKieu..I have added the network setting but still facing the same error

Comment: Hi All .. please help..I am still stuck in same error...